# Using redirect_to and error_messages_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do you get the error message to show up in error_messages_for in this example below?

In controller for create method:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @enquiry.save && @enquiry.valid?
    flash[:notice] = t('enquiry.messages.creation_success')
    format.html { redirect_to(@enquiry) }
    format.xml { render :xml => @enquiry, :status => :created, :location => @enquiry }
    format.json {
      render :json => @enquiry.compact.to_json
    }
  else
    format.html {
      @form_sections = get_form_sections
      render :action => 'new'
      }
      format.xml { render :xml => @enquiry.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

In view for new:

`<%= error_messages_for :enquiry %>`

In my model I have:

```
validates_presence_of :enquirer_name, :message =>   I18n.t("errors.models.enquiry.presence_of_enquirer_name")
validates_presence_of :criteria, :message => I18n.t("errors.models.enquiry.presence_of_criteria")
```

Comment: Perhaps show us what code you currently, what the output is that you're currently getting and what output you would like to get.

Comment: Alright, just added it

Comment: Are you trying to override the error object of you Enquiry model?  If yes, take a look at [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html)

Comment: I just want the original error object to show up.

Comment: Wasn't `error_messages_for` removed from Rails?

Comment: It's working for me in other parts of the application...